# How to solve CORS Policy problem in Strapi production build?

Tags: nginx, strapi

Does anyone now how to fix CORS errors for the Strapi backend? I am getting a similar message like the one below. I replaced my domain with example.com :

*Access to fetch at ‘https://blog.strapi.io/ghost/api/v0.1/posts/?client_id=ghost-frontend&client_secret=1f230799b4ec&limit=2’ from origin ‘http://backend.example.com:1337’ has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to ´http://backend.example.com:1337/admin´ preflight request doesn’t pass access control check: No ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request’s mode to ‘no-cors’ to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.*

I tried adding an origin to config/environments/production/security.json

**"origin": "*"**

**"origin": "backend.example.com"**

None of them worked. I am still getting the error.

I would apreciate some help on this.

Answer (score 6):

For me the following configuration worked:

```js
// file: root_project/config/middleware.js:

module.exports = {
  //...
  settings: {
    cors: {
      enabled: true, 
      // headers: '*', 
      origin: ["http://localhost", 'https://foo.example'],
    },
  },
};
```

Setting `headers: '*'` is the simplest use of the access control protocol. The server sends back an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, which means that the resource can be accessed by **any** origin.

If you wished to restrict access to the resource to requests only from https://foo.example, (so that no other domain than https://foo.example can access the resource in a cross-site manner), use the above setting, so that your server sends: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://foo.example`

**Note**: When responding to a credentialed requests request, the server **must** specify an origin in the value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, instead of specifying the "`*`" wildcard.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. I enabled "withCredentials" on my frontend after changing strapi permissions plugin to send me HttpOnly cookie with the JWT but of course, the CORS started complaining. Wanted to overwrite default strapi's origin: "*" but other options somehow did not work.

Comment: If you're using strapi v4 just like me, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70639958/strapi-v4-throwing-cors-exception)

Answer (score 2):

If you are in **production** then add the following content to **ProjectRoot/config/env/production/middleware.js**

**P.S.
*update origin with yourown custom list of urls.***

```
    module.exports = {
      load: {
        before: ["timer", "responseTime", "logger", "cors", "responses", "gzip"],
        order: [],
        after: ["parser", "router"],
      },
      settings: {
        timer: {
          enabled: true,
        },
        cors: {
          enabled: true,
          origin: [
            "https://www.example1.com",
            "http://www.example.com",
            "http://12.23.45.67:1234",
          ],
        },
      },
    };
```

make use of pm2 with necessary configuration for running the strapi project.

```
    module.exports = {
      apps: [
        {
          name: "server",
          cwd: "/home/userName/Project/ProjectRoot",
          script: "npm",
          args: "start",
          max_memory_restart: "450M",
          env: {
            PORT: 1337,
            DATABASE_HOST: "",
            DATABASE_PORT: 5432,
            DATABASE_NAME: "projectABC",
            DATABASE_USERNAME: "USER",
            DATABASE_PASSWORD: "PASSWORD",
          },
          env_production: {
            PORT: 1337,
            NODE_ENV: "production",
            DATABASE_HOST: "",
            DATABASE_PORT: 5432,
            DATABASE_NAME: "xyz",
            DATABASE_USERNAME: "postgres",
            DATABASE_PASSWORD: "abc",
          },
         },
        ],

    };
```

Answer (score 1):

The origin must be a array of urls.
Like following

```
origin: ["http://localhost", "https://backend.example.com"],
```

https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/concepts/middlewares.html#configuration-and-activation

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be fix by simply adding
`cors: { enabled: true, headers: '*' }`
in `./config/middleware.js`

Comment: This worked for me.
I have a question though - how will this affect security?

Comment: @MarkOkhman That's highly dangerous, that way you are exposing your API and it can be called from all webpages on the internet without any restrictions.

Answer (score -6):

https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/7296

upgrade and migration strapi version.