# Strapi v4 throwing cors exception

Tags: javascript, cors, strapi

Im new to strapi and I have downloaded strapi v4 and as front-end I use vue.js.

Now I created categories and I am trying to fetch those with my vue app but I’m getting a cors error.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:1337/api/categories' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

In the [documentation](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/configurations/required/middlewares.html#internal-middlewares-configuration-reference) I see I can override the origin on the cors middleware, but I don’t know how.

I’ve tried it with resolve and then set the config, but that breaks the cms.

```
  {
    resolve: 'strapi::cors',
    config: {
      origin: 'http://localhost:8080'
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After spending a few hours on the internet I finally got it working.

In my `config/middlewares.js` I had to replace `strapi::cors` to this:

```
module.exports = [
  ...
  {
    name: 'strapi::cors',
    config: {
      enabled: true,
      header: '*',
      origin: ['http://localhost:8080']
    }
  }
  ...
];
```

Don't forget to add port number, because it will not work if you don't.

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue and problems with Refilons answer, but a look in the official docs of strapi solved it: https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/configurations/required/middlewares.html#cors

The header property has to be plural: `headers: '*'`.

In middleware `config/middleware.js` replace `'strapi::cors',` with:

```
{
  name: 'strapi::cors',
  config: {
    enabled: true,
    headers: '*',
    origin: ['http://localhost:8080']
  }
},
```

As you read in the docs, you can also specify other cors properties like "methods".

"origin" can also be a String with '*' which allows all urls.

Answer (score 1):

This seem to work for me with "@strapi/provider-email-sendgrid":

middlewares.js

```
module.exports = [
  ...
  {
    name: "strapi::cors",
    config: {
      origin: ["*"],
      methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"],
      headers: ["Content-Type", "Authorization", "Origin", "Accept"],
      keepHeaderOnError: true,
    },
  },
  ...
];
```