# Setting cors in strapi 4

Tags: javascript, cors, localhost, strapi

I'm using strapi 4 as localhost and got a problem with cors settings when I add new assets via url

Image upload takes CORS error `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.countrysideveterinaryclinic.org/sites/default/files/interesting-cat-facts.jpg' from origin 'http://localhost:1337' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70639958/strapi-v4-throwing-cors-exception) from here didn't help

my `middleware.js`

```
module.exports = [
  'strapi::errors',
  'strapi::security',
  'strapi::poweredBy',
  {
    name: 'strapi::cors',
    config: {
      enabled: true,
      header: '*',
      origin: ['http://localhost:1337']
    }
  },
  'strapi::logger',
  'strapi::query',
  'strapi::body',
  'strapi::session',
  'strapi::favicon',
  'strapi::public',
];
```

Comment: What problem are you facing? If you're getting a CORS error message, add it to your question.

Comment: Note that [the documentation for Strapi's CORS middleware](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/configurations/required/middlewares.html#internal-middlewares-configuration-reference) mentions a `headers` (plural) property, but no `header` (singular) property.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I found the solution myself, maybe it will help someone

`middlewares.js`

```js
module.exports = [
  'strapi::errors',
  'strapi::security',
  'strapi::poweredBy',
  {
    name: 'strapi::cors',
    config: {
      enabled: true,
      headers: '*',
      origin: ['http://localhost:1337', 'http://example2']
    }
  },
  'strapi::logger',
  'strapi::query',
  'strapi::body',
  'strapi::session',
  'strapi::favicon',
  'strapi::public',
];
```

Comment: Note that in my case, `strapi::cors` was initially defined before `strapi::poweredBy` but it only works in exactly this order (cors must be after poweredBy not before).